# TypeError: QTableView.setSelectionModel

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

```
table = QtGui.QTableView()
table.setSelectionModel(QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Rows)
```

returns a `TypeError: QTableView.setSelectionModel(QItemSelectionModel): argument 1 has une
xpected type 'SelectionFlag'` error.

What is the right way to set the selection model for the `QTableView` widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change what gets selected when you activate a cell, you have to use:

```
table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QTableView.SelectRows)
```